An unintuitive expected value in a coin toss sequence
Originally I was investigating how to calculate the expected number of flips to obtain $n$ consecutive heads and $m$ consecutive tails. I played with $n=3$, $m=2$ for a fair coin, and arrive at an expected value that seemed unintuitive.
From now on let $n=3$, $m=2$, and let $X$ be the number of flips to achieve the goal. For clarity also let $M$ (resp. $N$) be the number of flips to obtain $m$ consecutive tails (resp. $n$) consecutive heads. Also assume the coin lands on its head with probability $1/2$. Define $H$ (resp. $T$) as the event that the first flip is a head (resp. tail). Conditioning on the first flip, we get
$$E[X]=1+\frac{1}{2}(E[X|H]+E[X|T]).$$ We can also condition $E[X|H]$ on the first position of a tail in the next $(n-1)$ flips. Since any tail in the next (n-1) flips resets the state to an initial $T$, we get
$$E[X|H]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(1+E[X|T])+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\cdot(2+E[X|T])+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\cdot(2+E[M]).$$
Let me note that the term $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\cdot(2+E[M])$ is for the next two flips being heads. From there we only need to obtain $m$ consecutive tails.
Similarly, we can condition $E[X|T]$ on the position of the first head in the next $(m-1)$ flips. We have
$$E[X|T]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(1+E[X|H])+\frac{1}{2}\cdot(1+E[N]).$$
Now let me use the fact that $E[M]=6$ and $E[N]=14$ to arrive at
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
E[X|H] =& 3+\frac{3}{4}E[X|T],\\
E[X|T] =& 8+\frac{1}{2}E[X|H].
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
We can then solve $E[X|H]=\frac{72}{5}$ and $E[X|T]=\frac{76}{5}$, resulting in
$$E[X] = \frac{79}{5}.$$ It seems to me a bit surprising that $$E[X|H]<E[X|T],$$ where there are less consecutive tails required. I simply want to check that my calculation was  correct.

I get the same results using the following Markov chain:

graphviz code of the image
Here the state "gottenAll" is absorbing. We can drop the "start" state. The quantities $\mathbb{E}[X|H]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X|T]$ are the expected number of steps before absorption when starting from the states H and T (of gotten nothing).
If we enumerate the states in the order
H, HH, T (of gotten nothing); H, T (of gotten HHH); H, HH, T (of gotten TT)
the transition matrix is
$$
Q = \frac{1}{2} \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
And the fundamental matrix is
$$
(I-Q)^{-1} =
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
 \frac{8}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \frac{8}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{12}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \frac{24}{5}\\
\frac{2}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{12}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & \frac{8}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{16}{5} \\
\frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{8}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{16}{5} & \frac{8}{5} & \frac{32}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 8
\end{array}\right)
$$
The expected number of steps before absorption is given by the sum of the row corresponding to the state where we start (in this case first for $H$ and third for $T$)
$$
\mathbb{E}[X|H] = \frac{8}{5} + \frac{4}{5} + \frac{6}{5} + \frac{8}{5} + \frac{4}{5} + \frac{12}{5} + \frac{6}{5} + \frac{24}{5} = \frac{72}{5}$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[X|T] = \frac{4}{5} + \frac{2}{5} + \frac{8}{5} + \frac{4}{5} + \frac{2}{5} + \frac{16}{5} + \frac{8}{5} + \frac{32}{5} = \frac{76}{5}
$$
I guess some sort of intuitive explanation is that since the sequence $HHH$ is harder to get than the shorter $TT$, it's better to have a head start in that.

Update
For the general case ($n>1$ heads and $m>1$ tails) we have the formulas
$$
\mathbb{E}[X|H]
= 2\left( \frac{2^m(2^m-1)}{2^m+2^n-2} +2^n-2 \right) \\
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[X|T] = 2\left( \frac{2^n(2^n-1)}{2^m+2^n-2} +2^m-2 \right) \\
$$
I got these by first considering a chain similar to the "gotten nothing"- block above where both HH..- n -..H and TT..- m -..T are absorbing and calculated the probabilities of ending up in HH...H starting from a particular state. And also the expected steps required.
The probability of reaching HH...H first when starting from H is $\frac{2^m} {2^m+2^n-2}$ and when staring from T it is $\frac{2^m-2} {2^m+2^n-2}$. The expected number of steps when starting from H is $\frac{2^{m+n+1}-2^{m+2}-2^{n+1}+4}{(2^m+2^n-2)}$. And $m,n$ swapped when starting from T.
Then the quantity $\mathbb{E}[X|H]$ is a sum of the expected steps in the first chain plus the weighted average of steps in the latter linear chains. After simplification we arrive at those rather short formulas. I wonder if there's more direct way to see them.
If we also generalize to $p = $ probability of heads, we have (denoting $q=1-p$)
$$
\mathbb{E}[X|H] = E_1 + a\frac{1-q^m}{pq^m}+(1-a)\frac{1-p^n}{qp^n}
$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
E_1 &= \frac{\left(1-p^{n-1}\right)\left(1-q^{m}\right)}{p\left(1-p^{n}-\left(1-p^{n-1}\right)\left(1-q^{m}\right)\right)} \\
a &= \frac{p^{n-1}}{p^{n-1}+q^{m-1}\left(1-p^{n-1}\right)}
\end{aligned}$$
And $\mathbb{E}[X|T]$ is gotten by $n,m$ swapped and $p,q$ swapped.

Thanks for checking with me, and I appreciate the effort a lot. I agree with you. What I am about to say is by no means rigorous, but I guess the luckiness to get HH after H surpass the easiness to get T after T.  If one gets lucky and get HHH first, they only need to get TT. If one gets TT, which easier, one still need to get HHH, which is much harder.

It will be interesting to see if the same phenomenon still holds if we fix $m=2$, and keep on increasing $n$.

Yes it will. In fact $\mathbb{E}[X|T]$ will approach $2^{n+1}-2$ and $\mathbb{E}[X|H]$ to $2^{n+1}-4$. So the difference approaches $2$. This is because those are the solutions to the linear chain (of just attaining HH.. (n times) ..H). The TT-block becomes meaningless: it will quite certainly be achieved as we keep trying for HH...H.

Indeed. I verified your statement with my method also!

I also generalized to unfair coin but can't see so simple form as in the symmetric case.

Agreed. I tried to write down the general case, and quickly decided that having the strategy to write down the general relation between $E[X|H]$ and $E[X|T]$ is good enough for me for now. Thanks again for all the hard work (salute).
